# How to do one-hot encoding of two similar columns into one?

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe where there are multiple columns that can have the same values (categorical variables), and I'd like to transform these values into a numerical value (binary). I have been trying to use the [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) function to achieve this, but I end up with lots of repetitive columns in the end (e.g. `Color1_green` and `Color2_green`).

An example dataframe of my input would be something like:

```
        User         Color1       Color2       Color3
0      Username1      green        red          blue
1      Username2      red          blue         NaN
2      Username3      green        yellow       NaN
```

As you can see, the variables `Color1`, `Color2` and `Color3` hold the same possible values, and they won't repeat values (so if `Color1` is `red`, `Color2` cannot be `red`).

What I'm trying to achieve is performing a one-hot encoding on these three color columns in order to get the following result:

```
        User          green       red       blue      yellow
0      Username1        1          1         1           0
1      Username2        0          1         1           0
2      Username3        1          0         0           1
```

Is there some way to this type of one-hot encoding using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `stack`, `get_dummies` and aggregate with `max`

```
out = df[['User']].join(
pd.get_dummies(df.filter(like='Color').stack())
  .groupby(level=0).max()
)
```

Output:

```
        User  blue  green  red  yellow
0  Username1     1      1    1       0
1  Username2     1      0    1       0
2  Username3     0      1    0       1
```